# iOS replicate inapp Purchase Error code 409

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

How is it possible to replicate the in app purchase error code 409 (Purchase already exist from AppStore)? One of my users is having this trouble and I want to trace back why the transaction isn't finished by the code. I know how to finish it, I just want to replicate the error so I can trace the flow inside the code.

It is Consumable Purchase.

Comment: It's almost impossible to help you without seeing what you have tried, logs or your function (code). Having said that I would suggest you create a sandbox user in iTunes connect and start debugging.

Comment: @Cliffordwh I don't need help in the code, I just want to replicate the situation of this error. Any idea how to replicate it?

Comment: Whether it is consumable or non-consumable in-app purchase category?

Comment: @Arasuvel it is consumable